# Matching cardinality graphs

Tags: graph-theory

Show that a graph $G$ contains a matching of cardinality $p$ if and only if $q(G−S) \le  |S|+|G|−2p, ∀S ⊆ V (G)$.

//Again a problem that i encountered in my book about graphs theory.Any tip would be appreciated//

Comment: What is $q(G−S) $?

Comment: I'm a little bit confused by your notation, but I'm thinking that this is some variant of Hall's condition. Hall's condition states that if the neighbors of every subset of G has a larger than the subset, then there is a perfect matching. So reapply that to $p$ instead of the entire graph.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming the notation $q(G - S)$ denotes the number of odd components in $ G - S$, and that $|G|$ is the number of vertices in the graph.

The Tutte-Berg formula is most useful in this situation.

> **Theorem (Tutte-Berg).** Where $\nu(G)$ denotes the size of a maximum matching of $G$, 
>   \begin{equation}
> \nu(G) = \frac{1}{2} \min_{U \subseteq V(G)}( |U| - q(G - U) + |V(G)|).
> \end{equation}

For neccesity, it is clear that if we have a matching of size $p$, then $p \leq \nu(G)$. Moreover, for any $S \subseteq V(G)$
\begin{align}
p \leq \nu(G) &\leq \frac{1}{2}(|S| - q(G - S) + |G|)\\
\implies 2p &\leq |S| - q(G - S) + |G|\\
q(G - S) &\leq |S| + |G| - 2p.
\end{align}
We are done this direction since $S$ was arbitrary.

Conversely, it is enough to show that $p \leq \nu(G)$ since if we can find a maximum matching $M$ then restricting $M$ so that the number of edges is $p$ allows us to conclude. Suppose for sake of a contradiction that $p > \nu(G)$ (remember, we don't know if there is a matching of size $p$ yet). Clearly then $-2p < \nu(G)$ and for some $S\ \subseteq V(G)$ satisfying $\nu(G) = \frac{1}{2} ( |S| - q(G - S) + |G|)$ from the formula, we have
\begin{align}
q(G - S) &\leq |S| + |G| - 2p\\
&< |S| + |G| - 2\nu(G)\\
&= |S| + |G| - (|S| - q(G - S) + |G|)\\
&= q(G - S).
\end{align}
That is, $q(G - S) < q(G - S)$, a contradiction. Therefore, $p \leq \nu(G)$ as desired, allowing us to conclude.